# jQuery(document).ready(function(){}); not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

In main.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    "use strict"
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(top>=60){
            $("nav").addClass('secondary');
        }
        else{
            if($("nav").hasClass('secondary')){
                $("nav").removeClass('secondary');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

In index.html

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

<head>
```

In style.css

```
.secondary{
    background-color:#34495e;
}
```

It is a code for changing the class of a navigation bar with class 'nav' to the class 'secondary' when the page scroll to downwards

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(top>=60){
            $("nav").addClass('secondary');
        }
        else{
            if($("nav").hasClass('secondary')){
                $("nav").removeClass('secondary');
            }
        }
    });
```

The above code doesn't works fine inside

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){});
```

but,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        "use strict"
        alert("hello world");
});
```

works fine and some other functions also works fine

but some functions not working.

can anyone help me to find the solution for this problem

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but you don't need to wait for the document to be ready before attaching a _scroll_ event handler on the `window`

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion to improve code performance. Always cache your initialized variables if you are going to use it multiple times. In your case, instead of using `$("nav")` over and over again, do something like `var nav = $("nav")` and use the variable `nav` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Check the value of `top` with `console.log` to make sure the scroll event is fired. Otherwise you will find an error about some other part of your code.

For example, this works and is also slightly optimised:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  var $win = $(window)
  var $nav = $("nav");

  $win.scroll(function() {
    var top = $win.scrollTop();

    console.log(top);

    if (top >= 60) {
      $nav.addClass("secondary");
    } else if ($nav.hasClass("secondary")) {
      $nav.removeClass("secondary");
    }
  });
});
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/taseenb/pen/QWbxRvP

Answer (score 0):

You can check what the error is on browser's inspect tool.
If you press "F12", "Developer tools" panel will be shown.
And click "Console" on this panel and check which error has been occured.

And I guess you need to use "jQuery" keyword to select elements.
Or please try following code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    "use strict"
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(top>=60){
            $("nav").addClass('secondary');
        }
        else{
            if($("nav").hasClass('secondary')){
                $("nav").removeClass('secondary');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

If you can share your page url, I can help you to check error and find a solution.

Comment: How can a same ` code ` from the question, be an answer?

Comment: $ has added.
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  -> jQuery(document).ready(function($){

Answer (score 0):

you can try on this, it works to me

put source script

```
<script th:src="@{/richtext/jquery.richtext.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/richtext/jquery.richtext.js}"></script>
```

then script text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($) {
         $('#shortDescription').richText();
        $('#fullDescription').richText();
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```